# Problemas de conexión Ubuntu WSL 2

Tags: linux, windows, docker, wsl

he intentado conectar mi Ubuntu por wsl 2 a internet y así poder usar mis repositorios de git entre otros comandos,

Esto es para el uso de Docker pero al querer usar ping u otro comando como el sudo apt update me marca el siguiente error:

[image: Error en la conexion]

En tanto mi conexion wsl de igual forma no tiene conexion nose si eso influya:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Docker funcionando de esta manera:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero me puedan ayudar o sugerir alguna alternativa que ya me acabe todas las que e visto en internet :(

Gracias de antemano!

Answer (score 0):

Cambia los servidores DNS de windows a los de google, que son tanto "8.8.8.8" como "8.8.4.4":

https://www.xataka.com/basics/como-cambiar-o-configurar-los-dns-en-windows-10

No pondré capturas de pantalla aquí, porque en aquel sitio está bien explicado y sería más un problema de interfaz gráfica.

Viendo que no funciona, intenta poner esta línea en tu archivo `sudo vim /etc/resolv.conf`:

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

Comment: Gracias por el apoyo pero me temo que no me a resultado

Comment: Supongo que puedes entrar a internet desde fuera de WSL

Comment: Actualicé mi respuesta, espero esto si funcione.

Comment: no se me hace que es algo de microsoft update ando probando eso

Answer (score 0):

Realice pruebas con Microsoft Update pero sigue sin funcionar lo raro es que realice el mismo proceso con mi laptop y ahí sin problema todo funciona

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]